# Version gradle for different modules

Tags: java, android, gradle, module

I am really confused about how gradle works with android subproject and simple server-java subproject tied to Project.

Android is using not the latest version of gradle, but my server app can use it.

Should I use the minimum version that supports all modules, or can I somehow edit the build file for each module?